# is this operating procedure an Abelian Group?

Tags: abelian-groups

I have to show if the following procedure gives a (Abelian) Group (G, *).

---

- $G = \{ \textrm{true}, \textrm{false} \}$
- $a*b := ( a \leftrightarrow b)$ (which means that $a$ is $\textrm{true}$ if and only if $b$ is $\textrm{true}$)

1.) Closure

For all $a,b \in G$, the result of the operation, $a * b$, is also in $G$.
This is NOT given, since $a,b$ are not in $G$. 
However, the result of the operation $a*b$ is in $G$.

Well, do I have show "Associativity, ..." for this procedure, when $a,b$ are not in $G$?
None of the group axioms are working.

Or am I misunderstanding this?

Thank you very much :)

Comment: Think of this as the group $\{-1,1\}$ where the operation is just usual multiplication

Comment: Okay.. So a and b ARE elements of G? Let's say tr*fa = fa, tr*tr = tr and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at the operation. It seems to be XNOR, giving $$\begin{array}{ccc}
  *              & \textrm{true}  & \textrm{false} \\
  \textrm{true}  & \textrm{true}  & \textrm{false} \\
  \textrm{false} & \textrm{false} & \textrm{true} \\
\end{array}$$

- By inspection of the table you have closure
- What's the identity?
- Does each element have an inverse?
- How can you show that $(a \leftrightarrow b) \leftrightarrow c = a \leftrightarrow (b \leftrightarrow c)$? (I see a few options. The most straightforward and least elegant would be to draw up two 8-row truth tables)

Comment: Ok.. CLOSURE is ok. IDENTITY - I need an element e with a*e=e*a=a... Well.. mh.. a*e=a means "True*True=True" or "False*True=False". In both cases e = true.. INVERSE: I need i with a*i=i*a=e. So true*true=true; false*false=true. The inverse for a is a?

Comment: @K.L., yes, each element is self-inverse.